# Transferring data from the js script to the controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

In the view (Index.cshtml) I have a button, when I click on that, the script that in the selectedItems writes the data is triggered. how are selectedItems transferred to the controller?

Button:

```html
    <form method="post" asp-action="Delete">
        <button type="submit" onclick="SelectedCheckbox()" class="btn-group col-md-2 col-md-offset-0">Remove</button>
    </form>
```

JS:

```html
function SelectedCheckbox() {
       var selectedItems = new Array();
       $("input[id='check']:checked").each(function () { selectedItems.push($(this).val()); });
    }
```

Controller (Users):

```html
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(string[] selectedUsers)
        {
...
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I tried to use ajax, but something does not work out:

```js
    function SelectedCheckbox()
    {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Users",
            contentType: "application/json",
            method: "POST",
            data: { parameters: parameters },
            success: function (data) {
            var data = new Array();
                $("input[id='check']:checked").each(function () { data.push($(this).val()); });
                alert(data.result);
            },
            error: function (data) { alert(data.responseText); }

        })
    }
```

```html
@model IEnumerable<Task1.Models.User>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Список пользователей";
}
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 
 
<div class="btn-toolbar nl container col-md-12" role="toolbar" aria-label="Menu">
 
    <form method="post" asp-action="Delete">
        <button type="submit" onclick="SelectedCheckbox()" name="delete" id="delete" class="btn-group col-md-2 col-md-offset-0">Remove</button>
    </form>
 
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff">
        <button type="submit" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 " role="group" aria-label="LogOff" />LogOff</button>
    </form>
</div>
 
<form asp-action="Delete">
    <div class="nl">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
            <tbody class="table-responsive ">
                <tr><th><input type="checkbox" class="all" data-id="d1" title="Выбрать все"></th><th>Login</th><th>Date of registration</th><th>Date Last Login</th><th>Block disabled</th></tr>
 
                @foreach (var user in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedUsers"
                                   id="@user.Id" value="@user.Id"
                                   class="styled">
                        </td>
                        <td>@user.UserName</td>
                        <td>@user.DateOfRegistration</td>
                        <td>@user.DateLastLogin</td>
                        <td>@user.LockoutEnabled</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
 
        </table>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function SelectedCheckbox() {
        var selectedItems = new Array();
        $("input[id='check']:checked").each(function () { selectedItems.push($(this).val()); });
        alert(selectedItems);

        return (selectedItems);
    }
</script>
```

I need to pass the value of the selected Item from the script in the method of removing the controller

Comment: What is your expected behavior ? How does your rendered HTML markup looks like ? What is the specific problem you are seeing ?

Comment: Also what is the point of redirecting from your action method if you are trying to make an AJAX call ? Also you should not have more than one item with same `Id` attribute value!

Comment: it seems to me that the problem in ajax